# How to validate two input fields in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT 2: I figured this out by saving all the answers in an array, and using `includes`. Thanks anyway to all who helped**

I am having difficulty validating two input fields. If it is just one, I feel like it would be a lot simpler, but there are two fields here.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <TextField
           label="Type (Cat/Dog/Fish)"
           variant="outlined"
           color='error'
           onChange={e => setUserInputPet(e.target.value)}
           value={userInputPet}
         />
         {showPetError && <Typography color='error'>Please enter Cat, Dog, or Fish</Typography>}

         <TextField
           label="Gender (Male/Female)"
           variant="outlined"
           color='error'
           onChange={e => setUserInputGender(e.target.value)}
           value={userInputGender}
         />
         {showGenderError && <Typography color='error'>Please enter Male or Female</Typography>}
</form>
```

Also have simple states for conditional rendering

```
const [showPetError, setShowPetError] = useState(false)
const [showGenderError, setShowGenderError] = useState(false)
```

Currently using so many `if statements` but I am targeting very specific cases and its not good and it hurts readability, plus I know there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

**All I want to do is:** The first input must accept either `cat` `dog` or `fish`. Otherwise, show an error. Similarly, the second input must accept either `male` or `female`. Otherwise, show an error.

Please help, I feel I am overcomplicating a simple issue. Even a simple `if statement` like this does not seem to work:

```
if (userInputPet.toLowerCase() !== 'dog' || userInputPet.toLowerCase() !== 'cat' || userInputPet.toLowerCase() !== 'fish' ) {
  triggerPetError()
}
```

I entered dog/cat/fish and it still shows the error

**EDIT**: As requested, below is the if statement that I have.  Apologies if it is messy/confusing, been working for a very long time. By the way the if statement **is not completed**, it just shows what I have been working on

```
if (
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'cat') ||
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'dog') ||
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'fish')

      &&

      (userInputGender.toLowerCase() === 'male') ||
      (userInputGender.toLowerCase() === 'female')

    ) {

      console.log('success');

    } else if (
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'cat') ||
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'dog') ||
      (userInputPet.toLowerCase() === 'fish')

      &&

      (userInputGender.toLowerCase() !== 'male') ||
      (userInputGender.toLowerCase() !== 'female')      

    ) {
      triggerGenderError()
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use the radio button instead ?

Comment: Could you share the many "if statements"? Since it seems to be where the issue really lies

Comment: @Cohars Have edited my OP

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is if you already have pre-defined set of answers, you can save it in arrays. Then all you have to check if user answers exists in the array or not.

Here is an example:

```
const typeArr = ['cat','dog','fish']
const genderArr = ['male', 'female']
```

Assuming you are storing the user input values in the states, do this:

```
if(!typeArr.includes(userTypeInput.toLowerCase()){
   setShowPetError(true)
} else if (!genderArr.includes(userGenderInput.toLowercase())){
   setShowGenderError(true)
}else{
   //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: This is literally, precisely what I just did 5 seconds ago. Came back here to edit my post to say I solved it. Thank you anyway